# Can Xcode utilize 64GB RAM or greater?

Tags: xcode, ram, compile-time

I have a MBP with 16GB of RAM. As projects grow in Xcode, the compile time does take longer. I'm looking into starting a hackintosh project purely for shortening Xcode compilation time. Since RAM is cheap, I wanna push the normal boundaries. But the biggest question is will Xcode be capable of using all the RAM greater than 32GB? I know there will be some diminishing marginal returns at some point of RAM increase.

Comment: Make sure you're actually RAM-bottlenecked first. Take a look at Activity Monitor while you're compiling. Typically with compilation you'll be limited by IO or processor speed rather than RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAM usage is mostly governed by the OS, because the Mac Pro does support up to 64GB of RAM, so should OSX (and by extension XCode).

Although I wonder if your compile time issues are actually RAM-related. I have Xcode projects that take minutes to build and it's all because my CPU is pegged at 100% (using a mid-2015 15" retina MBP). Not many software projects are RAM-constrained past 16GB.